# Facebook login issue codenameone

Tags: codenameone

The fb login is not working. It gives native facebook unsupported in both simulator and devices. loginSuccessful and loginFailed callbacks have no effect. Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException - Native facebook unsupported, if you are running on the Simulator use getAccessToken.

My code:

```
fbSignIn.addActionListener(e -> {  
    //These are used for the Oauth2 web login process on the Simulator.
    String clientId = "XXXXXXXXX";
    String redirectURI = "https://www.facebook.com/";
    String clientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXX99b66d012157";
    Login fb = FacebookConnect.getInstance();
    fb.setClientId(clientId);
    fb.setRedirectURI(redirectURI);
    fb.setClientSecret(clientSecret);

    // Sets a LoginCallback listener
    fb.setCallback(new LoginCallback() {
        public void loginSuccessful() {
            // we can now start fetching stuff from Facebook!
            System.out.println("success " + fb.getAccessToken().getToken());
        }

        public void loginFailed(String errorMessage) {
            System.out.println("login failure");
        }
    });

    // trigger the login if not already logged in
    if (!fb.isUserLoggedIn()) {
        fb.doLogin();
        System.out.println("dologin " + fb.getAccessToken().getToken());
    } else {
        // get the token and now you can query the Facebook API
        String token = fb.getAccessToken().getToken();
        System.out.println("token " + token);
    }
});
```

Error:

```
07-05 16:40:19.489: D/ViewRootImpl(22594): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
07-05 16:40:19.539: D/ViewRootImpl(22594): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
07-05 16:40:19.559: I/WebViewFactory(22594): Loading com.google.android.webview version 55.0.2883.91 (code 288309100)
07-05 16:40:19.589: W/ResourcesManager(22594): Resource getTopLevelResources for package com.google.android.webviewoverlayDirs =Null
07-05 16:40:19.599: I/art(22594): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
07-05 16:40:19.599: I/art(22594): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
07-05 16:40:19.609: I/art(22594): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
07-05 16:40:19.609: I/art(22594): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
07-05 16:40:19.609: I/cr_LibraryLoader(22594): Time to load native libraries: 1 ms (timestamps 7974-7975)
07-05 16:40:19.609: I/cr_LibraryLoader(22594): Expected native library version number "55.0.2883.91", actual native library version number "55.0.2883.91"
07-05 16:40:19.619: I/cr_LibraryLoader(22594): Expected native library version number "55.0.2883.91", actual native library version number "55.0.2883.91"
07-05 16:40:19.619: I/chromium(22594): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(163)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
07-05 16:40:19.629: I/cr_BrowserStartup(22594): Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
07-05 16:40:19.649: D/libEGL(22594): eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xffd6301c
07-05 16:40:19.709: D/SecWifiDisplayUtil(22594): Metadata value : SecSettings2
07-05 16:40:19.749: D/ScootOutForOwners(22594): [EDT] 0:0:0,1 - Codename One revisions: ac9852939f90d0d1c08890b87a7edbfed97017e1
07-05 16:40:19.749: D/ScootOutForOwners(22594): 2417
07-05 16:40:19.749: D/ScootOutForOwners(22594): [EDT] 0:0:0,3 - Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException - Native facebook unsupported, if you are running on the Simulator use getAccessToken
07-05 16:40:19.749: I/cr_Ime(22594): ImeThread is enabled.
07-05 16:40:19.749: W/System.err(22594): java.lang.RuntimeException: Native facebook unsupported, if you are running on the Simulator use getAccessToken
07-05 16:40:19.749: W/System.err(22594):    at com.codename1.social.FacebookConnect.getToken(FacebookConnect.java:138)
07-05 16:40:19.749: W/System.err(22594):    at com.codename1.social.FacebookConnect.getAccessToken(FacebookConnect.java:118)
07-05 16:40:19.749: W/System.err(22594):    at com.capitalEyeNepal.scoutOutForOwners.Home.lambda$new$1(Home.java:51)
07-05 16:40:19.749: W/System.err(22594):    at com.capitalEyeNepal.scoutOutForOwners.Home.access$lambda$1(Home.java)
07-05 16:40:19.749: W/System.err(22594):    at com.capitalEyeNepal.scoutOutForOwners.Home$$Lambda$3.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
07-05 16:40:19.749: W/System.err(22594):    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
07-05 16:40:19.749: W/System.err(22594):    at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:435)
07-05 16:40:19.749: W/System.err(22594):    at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:469)
07-05 16:40:19.749: W/System.err(22594):    at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:569)
07-05 16:40:19.749: W/System.err(22594):    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:2758)
07-05 16:40:19.749: W/System.err(22594):    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:2689)
07-05 16:40:19.749: W/System.err(22594):    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:3557)
07-05 16:40:19.749: W/System.err(22594):    at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:1967)
07-05 16:40:19.749: W/System.err(22594):    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:972)
07-05 16:40:19.749: W/System.err(22594):    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:901)
07-05 16:40:19.749: W/System.err(22594):    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
07-05 16:40:19.749: W/System.err(22594):    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
07-05 16:40:19.749: W/System.err(22594):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-05 16:40:19.749: W/cr_media(22594): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
07-05 16:40:19.789: E/chromium(22594): [ERROR:interface_registry.cc(104)] Failed to locate a binder for interface: autofill::mojom::PasswordManagerDriver
07-05 16:40:19.789: E/libEGL(22594): validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
07-05 16:40:19.789: D/libEGL(22594): eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xd9bff354
07-05 16:40:19.799: D/libEGL(22594): eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xd9bff4bc
07-05 16:40:19.809: W/AudioCapabilities(22594): Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L1
07-05 16:40:19.809: W/AudioCapabilities(22594): Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L2
07-05 16:40:19.809: W/AudioCapabilities(22594): Unsupported mime audio/x-ms-wma
07-05 16:40:19.809: W/AudioCapabilities(22594): Unsupported mime audio/x-ima
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.819: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.829: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unsupported mime video/wvc1
07-05 16:40:19.829: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
07-05 16:40:19.829: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unsupported mime video/wvc1
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv7
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv8
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unsupported mime video/mp43
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.839: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.849: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.849: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.849: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.849: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
07-05 16:40:19.849: W/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es
07-05 16:40:19.869: I/VideoCapabilities(22594): Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
07-05 16:40:19.889: D/libGLESv2(22594): STS_GLApi : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.capitalEyeNepal.scoutOutForOwners
07-05 16:40:24.599: D/ViewRootImpl(22594): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
07-05 16:40:24.669: D/ViewRootImpl(22594): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
07-05 16:40:24.699: I/System.out(22594): showKeyboard false
```

codenameone.properties.setting:

```
#
#Sun Jul 09 13:05:32 NPT 2017
codename1.arg.java.version=8
codename1.ios.appid=Q5GHSKAL2F.com.XXXXX.scoutOutForOwners
codename1.ios.release.provision=
codename1.arg.rim.obfuscation=false
codename1.arg.ios.newStorageLocation=true
codename1.j2me.nativeTheme=nbproject/nativej2me.res
codename1.arg.ios.project_type=ios
codename1.arg.ios.interface_orientation=UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait\:UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown\:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft\:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
codename1.displayName=ScootOutForOwners
codename1.android.keystoreAlias=XXXXXXXXXXXX
codename1.ios.release.certificate=
codename1.android.keystorePassword=XXXXXXXX
codename1.ios.provision=
codename1.arg.android.release=false
codename1.arg.ios.dsym=false
codename1.arg.facebook.appId=3100XXXXXXXXXXXXX
codename1.arg.ios.statusbar_hidden=false
codename1.languageLevel=5
codename1.android.keystore=C\:\\Users\\aa\\keystore.ks
codename1.vendor=CodenameOne
codename1.arg.win.ver=8
codename1.ios.certificatePassword=
codename1.ios.debug.certificatePassword=
codename1.mainName=Scootout
codename1.ios.release.certificatePassword=
codename1.arg.ios.prerendered_icon=false
codename1.ios.debug.certificate=
libVersion=168
codename1.arg.ios.application_exits=false
codename1.secondaryTitle=CodenameOne_Template
codename1.description=
codename1.ios.debug.provision=
codename1.arg.android.playService.plus=true
codename1.arg.j2me.nativeThemeConst=0
codename1.rim.certificatePassword=
codename1.version=1.0
codename1.ios.certificate=
codename1.icon=icon.png
codename1.rim.signtoolCsk=
codename1.arg.android.debug=true
codename1.rim.signtoolDb=
codename1.arg.ios.includePush=false
codename1.arg.ios.testFlight=false
codename1.packageName=com.XXXXXXXX.scoutOutForOwners
```

Comment: Did you set the build hints required for Facebook Login to work? Did you follow the instructions in the developer guide?

Comment: Yes I set facebook.appId in build hint. But I rechecked and it was not there. It auto disappears. I've to set it 2-3 times to save it. I don't know what happened. Now I get the token but fb.setCallback listener is not working. The code inside its methods are not working. Above I had printed "success" and "login failure" if loginSuccessful or failed but nothing in output when debugged.

Comment: Did you use the Codename One Settings app?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What do you mean by cn1 setting app? I jst set facebook.appId in build hint and the code is as above. Should I do anything else?

Comment: How did you set the build hint? What did you use to do that?

Comment: Right click on the project > properties > build hints . But my main problem now is that it is not calling fb.setCallback listener. loginSuccessful() and loginFailed() methods has no effect. I wonder why?

Comment: If native facebook login isn't integrated that means things won't work as expected so that means the build hint might be a problem. Can you look thru codenameone_settings.properties and see if the value for the build hint and other arguments make sense?

Comment: I think its alright in cn1_settings.properties. I can see fb_appId. I've updated the question with cn1 setting.properties file. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this more closely it seems you are using `getToken()` which has been deprecated with the message: `use getAccessToken() instead`.

Comment: No, I've used getAccessToken().getToken() and I get the token value as well. The main issue is that LoginCallback listener is not called and the methods inside it loginSuccessful() & loginFailed() has no effect.

Comment: Does `Display.getInstance().getProperty("facebook_app_id")` contain a value on the Android device that matches your facebook app id?

Comment: Its working now in new build but I didn't change the code. Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: We didn't change anything either.